# Is it possible that by "the ancient city of London" Twain refers to the Square Mile?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The phrase appears in *The Prince and the Pauper* by Mark Twain:

> In **the ancient city of London**, on a certain autumn day in the second quarter of the sixteenth century, a boy was born to a poor family of the name of Canty, who did not want him.

So, is Twain just saying that London is very old or is he referring here to the Square Mile?

Comment: In the 16th Century what is today the "City of London", nicknamed the "Square Mile", **was** London. Most of what we now think of as London was independent towns and villages and manors outside the city walls.

Answer (score 4):

If you read further, it seems likely Twain was indeed referring to the [City of London](http://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/) as opposed to the [city of London](https://www.london.gov.uk/), which would have been anachronistic— the surrounding area was not densely populated, and the County of London was not established until years after *The Prince and the Pauper* itself was published.

Tom Canty is described in Chapter II as growing up on Pudding Lane near London Bridge, very much in the City, though still in the city. But at the start of Chapter III,

> He wandered here and there in the city, hardly noticing where he was going, or what was happening around him…. He stopped and considered a moment, then fell into his imaginings again, and passed on **outside the walls of London**. The Strand had ceased to be a country-road then, and regarded itself as a street, but by a strained construction…. Tom discovered Charing Village presently, and rested himself at the beautiful cross built there….

The distinction between the old city and new (Westminster) is made [at other points](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1837/1837-h/1837-h.htm) as well, e.g.

> Yes, London and Westminster have been astir ever since the warning guns boomed at three o'clock…

and

> He followed the pageant through all its devious windings about London, and all the way to Westminster and the Abbey.

By New World standards, virtually any city in Europe is "ancient," and I'd wager most people outside of Britain are unaware of [the differences between the Londons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrObZ_HZZUc). But I would not say an awareness of the distinction is necessary in order to appreciate the themes of the work.